# Facebook share with javascript

Tags: javascript, share

I am using html javascript to share a link on facebook.
I am using this code:

```
<a href="javascript:"onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=test.com');"     target="_blank">
```

Share on Facebook

Now i want to replace test.com with the current url link in the browser .
How to do it !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current URL in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/get-current-url-in-javascript) // Your question is rather general, and not directly related to what the `facebook` tag stands for (tag removed), and could have resolved by doing a little proper research on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location` or `window.location.href` which provides the current URL. In your example, you can use something like the following:

```
<a href="javascript:" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + window.location);" target="_blank">
```

For more information see [Window.location on Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) which has the following description:

> The `Window.location` read-only property returns a `Location` object with information about the current location of the document.
>
> Though Window.location is a read-only Location object, you can also assign a `DOMString` to it. This means that you can work with location as if it were a string in most cases: `location` = '`http://www.example.com`' is a synonym of `location.href` = '`http://www.example.com`'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should work if you use `window.location.href`, so your code would be the following:

```
<a href="javascript:"onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + window.location.href);"     target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 0):

[window.location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) will get the current url e.g.

```
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + window.location.href);
```